Having trouble with Conditioning for Overdue tasks Power Automate
[Code for getting Today's Date] (https://i.sstatic.net/85hcL.png)
[Screenshot of Flow] (https://i.sstatic.net/ZeJmA.png)
[Overdue Condition] (https://i.sstatic.net/6SNsR.png)
Hi all,
so i created a Power Automate Flow to analyze an excel sheet which contains many tasks and their due date. The flow will automatically send out emails to the person responsible for each task if that task is due soon or already overdue. The due soon part is working fine but the overdue part is not. Even when the person's task is not overdue, there are emails being sent out saying it is, I have included pictures of my flow and the code for getting today's date and the overdue condition.
Thank you,
Joshua
I tried to initialize a new variable and tried to insert a code that will get me today's date in 'd-MMM-yy' format but no matter how much i tried it just doesn't work.

Can you share what you are using in the Compose action just before you conditions? Can you also share an example value from the outputs of the Compose of the flow run which isn't working?
